# No sound in LFS

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, lfs

I'm trying to install BLFS 8.4
I have successfully installed alsa-lib and alsa-utilities, the alsa-mixer also works fine. My sound card is "HDA Intel".
`speaker-test` also works but gives an undesirable output:

```
speaker-test 1.1.8

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 2048 to 8192
Period size range from 1024 to 1024
Using max buffer size 8192
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 1024
was set buffer_size = 8192
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.823178
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986632
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986640
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986624
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986635
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986632
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986626
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986631
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986632
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986633
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986628
 0 - Front Left
^[[5~Time per period = 2.986638
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986628
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 2.986633
 0 - Front Left
^CWrite error: -4,Interrupted system call
xrun_recovery failed: -4,Interrupted system call
Transfer failed: Interrupted system call
```

```
aplay -v /dev/urandom
Playing raw data '/dev/urandom' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
Plug PCM: Rate conversion PCM (48000, sformat=U8)
Converter: libspeex (external)
Protocol version: 10002
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : U8
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 8000
  exact rate   : 8000 (8000/1)
  msbits       : 8
  buffer_size  : 1365
  period_size  : 170
  period_time  : 21333
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 170
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 1365
  stop_threshold   : 1365
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 768426686420090880
Slave: Route conversion PCM (sformat=S32_LE)
  Transformation table:
    0 <- 0
    1 <- 0
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
  format       : U8
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 8
  buffer_size  : 8192
  period_size  : 1024
  period_time  : 21333
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 1024
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 8192
  stop_threshold   : 8192
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 4611686018427387904
Slave: Soft volume PCM
Control: PCM Playback Volume
min_dB: -51
max_dB: 0
resolution: 256
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S32_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 32
  buffer_size  : 8192
  period_size  : 1024
  period_time  : 21333
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 1024
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 8192
  stop_threshold   : 8192
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 4611686018427387904
Slave: Direct Stream Mixing PCM
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S32_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 32
  buffer_size  : 8192
  period_size  : 1024
  period_time  : 21333
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 1024
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 8192
  stop_threshold   : 8192
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 4611686018427387904
Hardware PCM card 0 'HDA Intel' device 0 subdevice 0
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S32_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 32
  buffer_size  : 8192
  period_size  : 1024
  period_time  : 21333
  tstamp_mode  : ENABLE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 1024
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 1
  stop_threshold   : 4611686018427387904
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 4611686018427387904
  boundary     : 4611686018427387904
  appl_ptr     : 0
  hw_ptr       : 2049^CAborted by signal Interrupt...
  aplay: pcm_write:2053: write error: Interrupted system call
```

```
paplay -v --raw /dev/urandom
Opening a playback stream with sample specification 's16le 2ch 44100Hz' and channel map 'front-left,front-right'.
Connection established.
Stream successfully created.
Buffer metrics: maxlength=4194304, tlength=352800, prebuf=349276, minreq=3528
Using sample spec 's16le 2ch 44100Hz', channel map 'front-left,front-right'.
Connected to device alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo (index: 0, suspended: no).
Stream started.
^CGot signal, exiting.ncy: 2260381 usec.
```

```
amixer
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono: Playback 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 104 [82%] [-17.25dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 104 [82%] [-17.25dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 15
  Front Left: Capture 8 [53%] [12.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 8 [53%] [12.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Disabled'
Simple mixer control 'Internal Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 3 [100%] [30.00dB]
  Front Right: 3 [100%] [30.00dB]
```

Also I cannot find `~/.asoundrc` and `/etc/asound.conf` and there is a config file in `/etc/alsa/conf.d` but no `alsa.conf` as given in the book. The command `locate libasound.so` is showing directory `/usr/lib/libasound.so` but there is no directory as `/usr/lib/alsa-lib/smixer` as given in the book.

Comment: So you don't have any sound output at all? Please post the output from `aplay -v /dev/urandom` and `paplay -v --raw /dev/urandom`

Comment: I don't know where to post the output. Therefore I edited the question. Please see that!

Comment: You did it right, that is the correct way to add more information, to edit the question... When running those commands, did either one output any sound?

Comment: No! None of the commands gave an output as sound.

Comment: Are your speakers/headphones plugged in to the correct jacks? Have you ever heard sound from this hardware and cable configuration before, even before LFS? Please post the output of `amixer`.

Comment: Yes, my laptop is good! I had Ubuntu and Windows 10 on my laptop before installing BLFS. None had any problem.

Comment: Everything looks good to me, have you tried a reboot?

Comment: Yes, I did reboot. Is the problem with the kernel configuration? Shall I reinstall alsa-lib and alsa-utilities?

Comment: It looks like all of your audio hardware is detected and enabled, at least to me... Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: `/etc/alsa/conf.d/*` is installed by the `alsa-plugins` package.  `~/.asoundrc` and `/etc/asound.conf` can be created manually if needed (I don't have them myself). There is also a boot script that is installed at the end of `alsa-utils`, `/etc/init.d/alsa` and a few `K` and `S` symlinks to it.

Comment: One needs alsa-lib and alsa-util for sound. So is there any alternative to that? Is there any problem with the BIOS?

Comment: It could happen that I didn't make a module of any needed driver in kernel and there are so many! My sound card is HDA Intel. Can you suggest anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have sound in my laptop!
I just made everything as module `<m>` under `Device Drivers -> Sound Card Support -> Advanced Linux Sound Architecture` and it worked!

Here is the output of `lsmod` for the modules that were needed:

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45056  1
snd_hda_codec_idt      49152  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    65536  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
snd_hda_codec          98304  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_idt
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_core           65536  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_idt
```